# How to set UWP app volume for the whole app level

Tags: uwp

In my UWP app, there are several MediaPlayers, and each can be set volume seperately.
But what I want is to set the app's volume, which may be the ceiling for all the MediaPlayers.
Does UWP have such method?
Thanks!

Comment: You can have a global variable for volume and assign it to the media player instance when you create it. IMO volume is based on the device and each media player instance have different volume option .

Comment: Other wise crate your own custom media player class which derives from MediaPlayer , so that you can set volume as fixed one. And use your custom media player instance , instead of default media player. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set UWP app volume for the whole app level

Currently, there is no better way to change the volume  you said. The user can change the UWP volume by using Volume Mixer. But there is no global app setting to change the system volume in UWP by writing some code.

[image]

For you requirement, you could use a global volume value to limit `MediaPlayers` max volume. And limit `MediaPlayer` in  `VolumeChanged` event handler.

```
public static double AppVolume = 0.5;
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

}
```

---

```
mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(Player);
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Volume = App.AppVolume;
mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.VolumeChanged += MediaPlayer_VolumeChanged;

private void MediaPlayer_VolumeChanged(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    if (sender.Volume > App.AppVolume)
    {
        sender.Volume = App.AppVolume;
    }
}
```